# Android - ScrollView with text fields causes background to flash

Tags: android, scrollview, textfield

I'm new to Android development and am having a problem. For my Android Activity I have a set of text fields inside a TableLayout. Prior to implementing ScrollView I had no issues, but with ScrollView I find that every time I select a text field or begin typing in it my background begins flashing black (using a white background). I'm not sure if this is an issue with my code or the emulator itself.

This is what I have for my ScrollView:

```
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="425px">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:background="@color/background">......
.....</TableLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

Anyone else have a similar problem?

Comment: "This is what I have for my ScrollView.........." ?

Comment: lol, what's this got to do with "flash"? That's not an appropriate tag just because the background is "flashing".

Comment: Yeah, that didn't cross my mind...my bad. This is my first post in StackOverflow and I can't seem to get my XML to display properly. Do you guys know why it's not displaying?

Comment: just paste your code with a "`" in front and "`" after it. Note: that's the little line thats below the ~ on your keyboard ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. You have done the same mistake. Eventually I found out that it has something to do with your background attribute.

Not Sure How it happens but

> Do Not Use @colour to set background instead use @drawable.

Make sure you remove all @colour from  XML.